# Tokenize an arbitrary string after a keyword until end-of-line in flex

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I have a program where I have a grammar rule like:

```
set_command
  : SET STRING set_option_value_opt
    {
      parse_set( $2, $3 );
    }
  ;

set_option_value_opt
  : /* empty */    { $$ = NULL; }
  | '=' STRING     { $$ = $2; }
  ;
```

That is, for the `SET` command, I want the name and optional value to be any non-whitespace-containing strings and I want the `parse_set()` function to do the parsing rather than specify it in the grammar.

In my flex file, I have:

```
letter       [A-Za-z_]
D            [0-9]
S            [ \f\r\t\v]

identifier   {letter}({letter}|{D})*

%x SET_OPTION

%%

{identifier} {
                keyword *k = keyword_find( yytext );
                if ( k != NULL ) {
                  if ( strcmp( yytext, "set" ) == 0 )
                    BEGIN( SET_OPTION );
                  return k->token;
                }
                return IDENTIFIER;
             }

<*>{S}+      ;                         /* ignore all other whitespace */

/* ... */

<SET_OPTION>{
  "="      { return '='; }
  ";"      { BEGIN( INITIAL ); return ';'; }
  \n       { BEGIN( INITIAL ); return END; }
  [^ \n]+  { return STRING; }
}
```

That is: when the lexer scans the `SET` token, switch the start state to `SET_OPTION`; when either `;` or `\n` is tokenized, switch back to the `INITIAL` state.  (Flex start scopes are described [here](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/flex_11.html).)

It correctly switches to the `SET_OPTION` state, but, when I enter a line and press *Return*, it never switches back to the `INITIAL` state.  After adding some debugging code, it never matches the `\n` inside the `<SET_OPTION>` scope.  Why not?  And how can I get what I want?

Comment: The first thing that will happen when you enter the `SET_OPTION` state will be to fail to match a space character, since there is no rule in `SET_OPTION` which deals with whitespace other than `\n`. But you don't mention that outcome. (Of course, the fact that a space is unexpectedly echoed might not be obvious). Perhaps there is something in the rules which you have elided which recognises whitespace. It's hard to provided useful suggestions seeing only a part of your code. Please provide a [mre]. Thanks.

Comment: Added more lexer rules.

Comment: Yeah, I read that code wrong. As written, that will not present the symptoms described in your question. So you need to provide a [mre], as suggested above.

Comment: Alternatively (or additionally), you might try to explain more clearly your evidence for "it never matches the `\n`". If your debugging code consists of `printf` calls (as opposed to `fprintf(stderr, ...)`), then it is possible that you just don't see the output because of buffering. A [mre] would answer that doubt as well.

Comment: I re-remembered that `flex` has the `-d` option and turned debugging on. Turns out, there was no `\n` but instead `EOF`, so I added a `<*><<EOF>>` rule and it works now.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working. I voted to close because the question left really has no applicability to anybody else's potential problem.

Comment: I dunno -- applicable to anyone using exclusive start states and explicitly matching EOF?